# bg color no white in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

when i use bootstrap5 dropdown in bg-dark navbar, dropdown background is black but use it the outside of navbar, dropdown background is white why?
i want to use white dropdown in dark navbar.
my complete code:
[MyCode](https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/WX9ttSRpP9Ac)

my navbar & dropdown:

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark " data-bs-theme="dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav  mb-3">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle show" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="true">
                        <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" data-bs-popper="static">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <ul class="navbar-nav  mb-3">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle show" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="true">
                <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu " data-bs-popper="static">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I don't find it dark even on nav bar. Can you make a working snippet?

Comment: yes that edited

Comment: Please make a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the Bootstrap class `bg-dark` to the `navbar`, Bootstrap adapts all other elements so that the UX (i.e., user experience) is the best possible. Why? If you have a dark gray navbar but the dropdown is white, there's too much contrast between these two colors. However, you can have a white dropdown in a dark gray navbar if you want.

Add the following CSS:

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-item {
    color: black;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-divider {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: black;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-item {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-divider {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark " data-bs-theme="dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

        <form class="d-flex ms-auto">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2"><i
                                class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="navbar-nav  mb-3">

          <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle show" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
              <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" data-bs-popper="static">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <ul class="navbar-nav  mb-3">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle show" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu " data-bs-popper="static">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```